# Make a custom block to render a published content

Tags: blocks, 8

Is there way to make a custom block displays a list of published contents?

I tried...

1. Create a new block type with just one field of type Reference->content.
2. Create a new block with recently created type.
3. Configure visibility -> type of content to a particular type of content on this recently created block.
4. Place block in block layout.
5. Publish a new content.

But at the end nothing is rendered on my page.

Drupal 8 question.

Comment: It might make more sense to create that block as a VIew. It'll be more configurable that way

Comment: I agree with Clive. This is what the Views module is made to do.

Comment: Thanks for replay, I'm new in Drupal and getting the "drupal way of thinking " yet. Any advices are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to achieve this problem is by creating a view block. That only show the content that is been published. Then you going to add that view block on any region that you wish.

Here is the code for a export view block that only show content that have been published.

```
uuid: 36b6dd0f-8a30-4d08-a718-24afe8b4cfc0
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - node
    - user
id: content_published
label: 'Content Published'
module: views
description: ''
tag: ''
base_table: node_field_data
base_field: nid
core: 8.x
display:
  default:
    display_plugin: default
    id: default
    display_title: Master
    position: 0
    display_options:
      access:
        type: perm
        options:
          perm: 'access content'
      cache:
        type: tag
        options: {  }
      query:
        type: views_query
        options:
          disable_sql_rewrite: false
          distinct: false
          replica: false
          query_comment: ''
          query_tags: {  }
      exposed_form:
        type: basic
        options:
          submit_button: Apply
          reset_button: false
          reset_button_label: Reset
          exposed_sorts_label: 'Sort by'
          expose_sort_order: true
          sort_asc_label: Asc
          sort_desc_label: Desc
      pager:
        type: some
        options:
          items_per_page: 5
          offset: 0
      style:
        type: default
      row:
        type: fields
      fields:
        title:
          id: title
          table: node_field_data
          field: title
          settings:
            link_to_entity: true
          plugin_id: field
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: string
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
      filters:
        status:
          value: true
          table: node_field_data
          field: status
          plugin_id: boolean
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: status
          id: status
          expose:
            operator: ''
          group: 1
      sorts:
        created:
          id: created
          table: node_field_data
          field: created
          order: DESC
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: created
          plugin_id: date
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          exposed: false
          expose:
            label: ''
          granularity: second
      title: 'Content Published'
      header: {  }
      footer: {  }
      empty: {  }
      relationships: {  }
      arguments: {  }
      display_extenders: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      tags: {  }
  block_1:
    display_plugin: block
    id: block_1
    display_title: Block
    position: 1
    display_options:
      display_extenders: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      tags: {  }
```